# Select query is taking too much time by using variable as parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apps

When I am running below query by hardcoded in where condition it runs fast:

```
... AND ooha.order_number BETWEEN NVL(5339914,ooha.order_number) 
    AND NVL(5339914,ooha.order_number)
```

But when I taking it in a parameter it is taking too much time almost more than 2 hours

```
... AND ooha.order_number BETWEEN NVL(:p,ooha.order_number) 
    AND NVL(:q,ooha.order_number)
```

below is my original code please look into this as I tried all possible solution as per developer point of view:

```
SELECT ooha.order_number,
    hps.addressee cus_name,
    oola.line_number,
    (SELECT rtrim(extract(xmlagg(xmlelement("a",set_name                        -- query to check ship_set
      ||'/')),'//text()'),',')
    FROM oe_sets
    WHERE header_id = ooha.header_id
    AND set_type    = 'SHIP_SET'
    ) ship_set,
  msib.segment1 item_name,
  ooha.booked_date,
  oola.schedule_ship_date,
  mp.ORGANIZATION_CODE,
  oola.ordered_quantity,
  oola.subinventory,
  oola.project_id,
  (SELECT description FROM fnd_user WHERE user_id = ooha.attribute12            -- query to check Customer Delivery Partner  
  ) cdp,
  (SELECT NVL(SUM(reservation_quantity),0)                                      -- query to check Reservation Quantity
  FROM mtl_reservations
  WHERE demand_source_line_id = oola.line_id
  ) reserved_qty,
  oola.header_id,
  oola.line_id,
  msib.inventory_item_id,
  msib.organization_id,
  msib.item_type,
  msib.inventory_item_status_code,
  cic.item_cost,
  msib.ATTRIBUTE13

FROM oe_order_headers_all ooha,
  oe_order_lines_all oola,
  mtl_system_items_b msib,
  hz_cust_site_uses_all csu ,
  hz_cust_acct_sites_all cas ,
  hz_party_sites hps,
  mtl_parameters mp,
  cst_item_costs cic
WHERE ooha.header_id       = oola.header_id
AND oola.inventory_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
AND oola.ship_to_org_id    = csu.site_use_id
AND csu.cust_acct_site_id  = cas.cust_acct_site_id
AND cas.party_site_id      = hps.party_site_id
AND oola.ship_from_org_id  = msib.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND msib.ORGANIZATION_ID   = mp.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND cic.inventory_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
AND cic.ORGANIZATION_ID = msib.ORGANIZATION_ID
and cic.COST_TYPE_ID=1
AND oola.SUBINVENTORY LIKE 'Direct'
AND oola.item_type_code IN ('CONFIG','STANDARD')
AND oola.project_id       IS NOT NULL
AND OOLA.BOOKED_FLAG       = 'Y'
AND OOLA.OPEN_FLAG = 'Y' AND oola.ship_from_org_id IN
(SELECT ood.organization_id
FROM org_organization_definitions ood
WHERE ood.operating_unit =
  (SELECT operating_unit                                                        -- query to fetch operating unit
  FROM org_organization_definitions ood1
  WHERE ood1.organization_id = 2064
  )
) 
AND ooha.order_number BETWEEN NVL(5339914,ooha.order_number) AND NVL(5339914,ooha.order_number)
AND TRUNC(oola.schedule_ship_date) >= TRUNC(NVL(TO_DATE(null,'DD-MON-YYYY'),oola.schedule_ship_date))
AND TRUNC(oola.schedule_ship_date) <= TRUNC(NVL(TO_DATE(null,'DD-MON-YYYY'),oola.schedule_ship_date))
```

-- end of cursor select query

Comment: What's your `cursor_sharing` parameter ? `exact` .. ?

Comment: You may need to look at the query plan for the fast query and give hints for the one with the parameter.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Its order_number

Comment: No I didn't ask for the column of the table, but about the DB or session parameter called `cursor_sharing`, I mean you might be using `exact` as value for that parameter. You may consult DBA to get the value for that parameter.

Answer (score 4):

> ... AND ooha.order_number BETWEEN NVL(:p,ooha.order_number) 
>       AND NVL(:q,ooha.order_number)

Well, that's a tall order for Oracle to optimize.  If the bind variables are both non-null and cover a reasonable range, an index range scan with nested loops is probably a good plan.  But the next call might specify two null values for :p and :q, in which case the index range scan / nested loop plan would be disastrous.

Recent versions of Oracle (starting with 11g, iirc) have the concept of bind-aware and bind-sensitive cursors.  The feature is called adaptive cursor sharing, if you want to read up on it.
With that feature, if you run this query enough, Oracle should catch on to the fact that different bind values require different plans so that, eventually, your performance becomes better.  Using the `/*+ BIND_AWARE */` hint may help this process along.

Honestly, I've never had as much luck with the feature as I would like.

If you want, you can help make the optimizer's life a little easier by doing some of its work for it.  Namely, split your access of `ooha` into 4 parts: (a) both binds not null, (b) p null, q not null, (c) p not null, q null, and (d) both binds null.

For example:

```
select count(*)
from   ( SELECT * 
         FROM   oe_order_headers_all ooha
         WHERE  ooha.order_number between :p and :q
         and    :p is not null
         and    :q is not null
         UNION ALL
         select *
         from   oe_order_headers_all ooha
         WHERE  ooha.order_number >= :p
         and    :p is not null
         and    :q is null
         UNION ALL
         select *
         from   oe_order_headers_all ooha
         WHERE  ooha.order_number <= :q
         and    :p is null
         and    :q is not null
         UNION ALL
         select *
         from   oe_order_headers_all ooha
         WHERE  :p is null
         and    :q is null ) ooha;
```

It shouldn't be necessary to do this -- and it's unfortunate to need to do it.  But, sadly, sometimes it does help and I find that it can be faster and more reliable than hoping/waiting for adaptive cursor sharing to save me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Matthew. Could you please suggest where should I use this in the cursor? Do I need to put multiple SELECT statements in the Cursor by using UNION ALL because when I added ur suggested code in where condition it goes into infinite again?

Comment: You can split your whole query into the four parts I mentioned, but that will involve duplicating all your other query logic into each part.  Or, you can try putting the four parts shown above in as a replacement for the OOHA table in your query.  E.g., instead of `FROM oe_order_headers_all ooha`, use `FROM ( SELECT...UNION ALL SELECT... etc)` as above.

Comment: I replaced in FROM but still no luck

Comment: @AnshulAyushya "no luck" is completely unhelpful.  Update your question with what you're trying and what error or other bad outcome you're getting.

Comment: sorry for miss understanding.. no luck means its taking same, too much time ether using union all in the entire select statement or adding it in FROM table

Comment: With so many tables, it could be any number of things.  I would suggest that you take advantage of the fact that, if the lines are open and booked, that the header also must be opened and booked (I recognized your data model as being Oracle's Order Management product).  Create an index on `OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL(open_flag, booked_flag, order_number)` and then use conditions: `ooha.open_flag = 'Y' AND ooha.booked_flag = 'Y' AND ooha.order_number between nvl(:p_from,ooha.order_number) and nvl(:p_to, ooha.order_number)`.

Comment: Also, consider avoiding `ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS` - it's a view that can sometimes confuse things.  Look at it's definition: you can get everything you need from the table `HR_ORGANIZATION_INFORMATION HOI WHERE HOI.ORG_INFORMATION_CONTEXT = 'Accounting Information'`.  The operating unit ID is in column `ORG_INFORMATION3`.

Comment: order_number already has an index and booked_flag and open_flag are different columns of another table, oe_order_lines_all oola...

Comment: You misunderstood me.  The `OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL` table also has columns `BOOKED_FLAG` and `OPEN_FLAG` in the Oracle Order Management data model.  If your lines are booked and open, your headers are as well.  So, re-read my previous comment, understanding that all the columns described are in `OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL`.  Anyway, this is a general SQL tuning problem, no longer related to your OP.  Good luck.  Sorry I wasn't more help.